# OkHttp requests are delayed

Tags: arm, java-8, java, retrofit2, okhttp

Using OkHttp3 with Retrofit to send simple post request to a service inside local network. I use the same implementation in different projects. The only difference in the scenario is it runs on raspberry pi (armv6l) platform. 
The symptom is simply explained i invoke a request synchronous or asynchronous doesn't make a difference and those request are executed delayed for from around 30 up to 60 seconds.
I don't know what to do and investigate it deeper. Also wireshark exposes me exactly the same.
If i invoke the request via cURL it works as expected.

Thank you for all assistance to solve this issue.